# python3 multiprocessing queue deadlock when use thread and process the same time

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I used multi-processes to handle cpu intensive task,I have a thread reading data from stdin and put it to a input_queue,  a thread get data from output_queue and write it to stdout, multiple processes get data from input queue,then handled the data,and put it to output_queue.But It some times will block forever,I doubt that it was because inappropriate to use the multiprocessing Queue,But I don't know how to solved it,can anyone help me?
my code as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue


def write_to_stdout(result_queue: Queue):
    """write queue data to stdout"""
    while True:
        data = result_queue.get()
        if data is StopIteration:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()


def read_from_stdin(queue):
    """read data from stdin, put it in queue for process handling"""
    try:
        for line in sys.stdin:
            queue.put(line)
    finally:
        queue.put(StopIteration)


def process_func(input_queue, result_queue):
    """get data from input_queue,handled,put result into result_queue"""
    try:
        while True:
            data = input_queue.get()
            if data is StopIteration:
                break
            # cpu intensive task,use time.sleep instead
            # result = compute_something(data)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            result_queue.put(data)
    finally:
        # ensure every process end
        input_queue.put(StopIteration)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # queue for reading to stdout
    input_queue = Queue(1000)

    # queue for writing to stdout
    result_queue = Queue(1000)

    # thread reading data from stdin
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_stdin, args=(input_queue,))
    input_thread.start()

    # thread reading data from stdin
    output_thread = threading.Thread(target=write_to_stdout, args=(result_queue,))
    output_thread.start()

    processes = []
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    # start multi-process to handle some cpu intensive task
    for i in range(cpu_count):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_func, args=(input_queue, result_queue))
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)

    # joined input thread
    input_thread.join()

    # joined all task processes
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()

    # ensure output thread end
    result_queue.put(StopIteration)

    # joined output thread
    output_thread.join()
```

test environment:

```
python3.6
ubuntu16.04 lts
```

Comment: Has anyone encountered a similar problem?